# How to plot IBM Watson NLU API JSON output using Plotly?

Tags: python, api, plotly, ibm-watson

I used IBM Watson NLU API and fetched keywords from the response in JSON format. Now, I want to plot a graph by taking 'x'='text' ,'y'='count' using plotly but don't know how to do this.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ymXf.png)

Comment: When posing example, use text rather than images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no easy or direct way to achieve this. You may have to use a library like pandas to transform the JSON output in to format plotly can plot on a chart.

You can start with Pandas 101 - https://plot.ly/pandas/intro-to-pandas-tutorial/

Here's the Plotly Bar chart with text and count data plotted using Jupyter notebook on IBM Watson studio
[image]

Plotly code:

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

NLU_data = [go.Bar(x=NLU_df.text, y=NLU_df['count'].tolist())]

py.iplot({ 'data': NLU_data,
            'layout': {
               'title': 'Distribution',
               'xaxis': {
                 'title': 'text'},
               'yaxis': {
                'title': 'count'}
        }})
```

You can find the [Jupyter notebook here](https://gist.github.com/VidyasagarMSC/f98f44740862eba23ef6e7ae41f65842) with complete code for your reference

Comment: Thanks Its really Helpful

Answer (score 2):

If your JSON object was called `response` then this sample code will convert it into a pandas dataframe and display it as a graph.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(response['keywords'], columns=['text', 'relevance', 'count']) 
df.plot(kind='barh', x='text', y='count')
```

It will display something like this:

[image]